# Get text with javascript textContent

Tags: javascript

I try to get text from a site, using javascript and textContent

i use this code

```
var markets=document.getElementsByClassName('sip-MarketGroup ')
for (var i=0;i<markets.length;i++){
    try {
       console.log(markets[i].textContent);
    } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
    }
}
```

a part of html into the site is this below

```
<div class="sip-MarketGroup">
    <div class="sip-MarketGroupButton sip-MarketGroup_Open ">
        <div class="sip-MarketGroupButton_Text " style="">Fulltime Result</div>
        <div class="sip-MarketGroupButton_FavouriteButton sip-FavouriteButton ">
            <div class="sip-FavouriteButton_SVG "> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gl-MarketGroup_Wrapper ">
        <div class="gl-MarketGroupContainer ">
            <div class="gl-Market gl-Market_General gl-Market_General-topborder gl-Market_General-pwidth100 ">
                <div class="gl-Participant gl-Participant_General gl-Market_General-cn3 ">
                    <span class="gl-Participant_Name">QPR</span>
                    <span class="gl-Participant_Odds">12.00</span>
                </div>
                <div class="gl-Participant gl-Participant_General gl-Market_General-cn3 ">
                    <span class="gl-Participant_Name">Draw</span>
                    <span class="gl-Participant_Odds">4.00</span>
                </div>
                <div class="gl-Participant gl-Participant_General gl-Market_General-cn3 ">
                    <span class="gl-Participant_Name">Bournemouth</span>
                    <span class="gl-Participant_Odds">1.36</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i get

> Fulltime ResultQPR12.00Draw4.00Bournemouth1.36

without spaces, how can i get this text but seperated with ";" like this

> Fulltime Result;QPR 12.00;Draw 4.00;Bournemouth 1.36;

Comment: You are going to have to select the elements inside of that and join those together

Comment: What is `sip-MarketGroup` exactly since it is not shown in your code.

Comment: I have fixed that now

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the method "innerText" instead?
And you can do the following:

```
var markets=document.getElementsByClassName('sip-MarketGroup ')
for (var i = 0; i < markets.length; i++) {
   try {
      console.log(markets[i].innerText.split('\n').join(';'));
   } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
   }
}
```

But you can always remove the `.join(';')` and just use the array to do whatever you need :) Maybe even string interpolation!

Give me a heads up if you liked my answer!

Happy New Year!

Pedro